# blazeds push message not working when tomcat is fronted by apache server (though the rpc works)

Tags: apache, tomcat, blazeds

When using blazeds with apache tomcat, the rpc calls and push messaging system work. But when apache server is placed in front of apache tomcat, only the rpc calls work, the blazeds push messaging does not work. Hope someone has a fix to this and i would be glad if such person is willing to share his/her configuration set-up that worked.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Had exactly the same problem too and here is the gist. You are probably using the SteamingAmf. The Apache Server doesnt want you leaving a perpetual open connection to the underlying server and as such buffers your data.

To make everything work you will have to use the polling version. here is a smaple of the configuration you need to do in your services-config.xml

```
<channel-definition id="my-polling-amf" class="mx.messaging.channels.SecureAMFChannel">
  <endpoint url="https://{server.name}:{server.port}/{context.root}/messagebroker/amfpolling" class="flex.messaging.endpoints.SecureAMFEndpoint"/>
<properties>
    <polling-enabled>true</polling-enabled>
    <polling-interval-millis>0</polling-interval-millis>
    <wait-interval-millis>60000</wait-interval-millis>
    <client-wait-interval-millis>3000</client-wait-interval-millis>
    <max-waiting-poll-requests>100</max-waiting-poll-requests>
</properties>
</channel-definition>
```

For the above configuration I am using https.

Configure your messaging-config.xml as follows

```
  <destination id="DestinationID">
    <channels>
    <channel ref="my-polling-amf"/>
    </channels>
    <adapter ref="DestinationAdapter"/>        
  </destination>
```

This should work assuming that your original setup was working. Good luck.